# How to rotate png image Delphi?

Tags: delphi, image-processing, rotation

How can I rotate a png image in Delphi with preserving its transparency?
I loaded it via `TPNGObject`.
I'm then using `Canvas.StretchDraw(MyRect, the TPNGObject)` but I don't know how to rotate it.

Comment: I haven't used it for rotation, but you might try the freeware at www.graphics32.org if you don't get a better answer here.

Comment: I suspect this will be slow and painful in VCL, slow and easy in graphics32 + VCL, and fast and easy in Firemonkey (FMX) in XE2.

Comment: Following the link in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437714/resize-png-image/2439466#2439466) will lead to example code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that if you do a rotate using the Canvas, you will lose your transparency, as you noted with TPNGObject.

This is because the Canvas doesn't support transparency at the level required by a PNG image.

Instead, you must use specialized code to rotate the PNG image. Here is a link to a library of code that supports the TPNGObject, including a function to rotate it:
http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/25631

Comment: Thanks Marcus so much ..but do you have any idea how to fasten this code because he uses a for loop over the width and height.