# PNG image rotation component

Tags: delphi, png, delphi-7

Can anyone help me in finding a component or SDK that rotates PNG images quickly whilst retaining transparency?

Comment: I used the normal rotation of each pixel but it was so slow, i know how to open it but i want to fast rotate it

Comment: Take a look at [Vampyre Imaging](http://imaginglib.sourceforge.net/index.php). It has a nice demo included and works pretty fast. And it's still alive.

Comment: Maybe a look at http://www.delphiarea.com/products/delphi-components/rotateimage/

Comment: Thanks Andreas, i have tried this before but the componenet does not accept png images

Comment: @DavidHeffernan,I tried to searcho ver there but i couldn't find a component for png rotation

Comment: No, the rotation will need to be done with a `TBitmap32` component and then transferred back to a PNG

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Thanks David but this component rotates only 90,180, or 270 degrees :)

Comment: Use affine transformations to achieve general rotations. Also note that graphics32 is rather pluggable and so you may find that extensions are sometimes useful. Anyway, it's up to you but I think graphics32 would be my starting point.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to rotate png image Delphi?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228868/how-to-rotate-png-image-delphi)

Answer (score 3):

The original author of the PNGImage component (the basis of the Delphi native component) had a forum where he, and others, posted code snippets on how to do things using the PNGImage component.

Before the forum was taken down I grabbed a copy of all of the code snippets and placed them on the CodeGear Code Central website.

Most if not all of these work with native PNG images and do maintain the Alpha channel.

Here is the complete list of examples included in the package:

```
Smooth rotates a PNG object
Resizes a TPNGObject using a smooth algorithm
Slice one PNG into several smaller ones
Saves an image as either a bitmap or a png.
Sample chunk descendant
Read all tEXt-Chunks and write values into a TStrings object
Display a message box with information extracted from the PNG File
Finds and cuts a block from a PNG image
This method converts the png into a jpeg object
This method converts the png into a bmp object
Overlay one PNG over another
This makes the image half transparent
Flips a png image vertically and saves back
Draws a png image over the desktop
```

Here is the link: [CodeCentral PNG Methods](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/25631)

**EDIT**

Here is a highly optimized version of a RotatePNG function.
It still, technically, goes pixel by pixel but it uses a number of techniques, such as scanlines, pointer math and storage of image dimensions to achieve a decent speed increase.

I used a 2550x3300 pixel image (~5MB) for testing and by using semi-rough, but totally (non)scientific calculations (counting in my head) I came up with the following metrics:

`the old routine (mentioned above):`**`~7 seconds`**
`the new routine (code below):`**`~1.5 seconds`**

I can't strictly take credit for this.  The code originally came from from [EFG's website](http://www.efg2.com/)  and I decided to try my hand at converting one of those routines to rotate PNG images instead of bitmaps.

I'm sure anyone who knows more about this type of thing will take a look at the code and offer up some suggestions to tweak more speed out of it.

```
procedure RotatePNG(
        const PNGOriginal:TPNGImage;//input PNG 
        out   PNGRotated:TPNGImage; //output PNG
    Const Angle : double);
{
  (c) har*GIS L.L.C., 1999
    You are free to use this in any way, but please retain this comment block.
    Please email questions to jim@har-gis.com .
    Doc & Updates: http://www.efg2.com/Lab/ImageProcessing/RotateScanline.htm
    and http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Library/Delphi/Graphics/JimHargis_RotateBitMap.zip
}
{
  Modified by R.J.Mills, 2012 - 
    - Use pointer arithmetic instead of type sub-scripting for faster pixels.  
    - Converted to rotate PNG images June 2012.
}

Type
  TRGBTripleArray = array [0..32767] of TRGBTriple; //allow integer subscript
  pRGBTripleArray = ^TRGBTripleArray;

VAR
  wPng : TPngImage;
  theta:Double;  // rotn angle in radians counterclockwise in windows
  cosTheta       :  Single;   {in windows}
  sinTheta       :  Single;
  i              :  INTEGER;
  iOriginal      :  INTEGER;
  iPrime         :  INTEGER;
  j              :  INTEGER;
  jOriginal      :  INTEGER;
  jPrime         :  INTEGER;
  NewWidth,NewHeight:INTEGER;
  nBytes: Integer;//no. bytes per pixelformat
  Oht,Owi,Rht,Rwi: Integer;//Original and Rotated subscripts to bottom/right
  RowSizeRot : integer;
  RowSizeOrg : integer;
  AlphaSizeRot : integer;
  AlphaSizeOrg : integer;
  RowStartPtr : Pointer;
  AlphaStartPtr : Pointer;

  RowRotatedT: pRGBtripleArray; //3 bytes
  AlphaRowT: pByteArray;    //1 byte
  AlphaRotatedT : pByteArray;   //1 byte

  TransparentT: TRGBTriple;

{=======================================}
 function Mod360( const angle:Double ):Double;
 begin
   result := frac( angle/360 )*360;
   if result < 0 then
     result := result+360;
 end;
{=======================================}

begin
  Theta := -(2*pi* Mod360(angle))/360;
  sinTheta := SIN( theta );
  cosTheta := COS( theta );

    NewWidth  := ABS( ROUND( PNGOriginal.Height*sinTheta) ) + ABS( ROUND( PNGOriginal.Width*cosTheta ) );
    NewHeight := ABS( ROUND( PNGOriginal.Width*sinTheta ) ) + ABS( ROUND( PNGOriginal.Height*cosTheta) );

  if ( ABS(theta)*MAX( PNGOriginal.width,PNGOriginal.height ) ) > 1 then
  begin//non-zero rotation

    wPng := TPngImage.createblank(PNGOriginal.Header.ColorType, 8, NewWidth, NewHeight);
    try

    //local constants for loop, each was hit at least width*height times   1/8/00
      Rwi := NewWidth - 1; //right column index
      Rht := NewHeight - 1;//bottom row index
      Owi := PNGOriginal.Width - 1;    //transp color column index
      Oht := PNGOriginal.Height - 1;   //transp color row  index

      RowRotatedT := wPng.Scanline[ Rht ] ;

      RowStartPtr := PNGOriginal.Scanline[ 0 ];
      RowSizeRot := Integer(wPng.ScanLine[1])-Integer(wPng.ScanLine[0]);
      RowSizeOrg := Integer(PNGOriginal.ScanLine[1])-Integer(PNGOriginal.ScanLine[0]);

      TransparentT := pRGBtripleArray( PNGOriginal.Scanline[ Oht ] )[0];

      if PNGOriginal.Header.ColorType in [COLOR_RGBALPHA] then
      begin
        AlphaRowT := PNGOriginal.AlphaScanline[ Oht ];
        AlphaStartPtr := PNGOriginal.AlphaScanline[ 0 ];
        AlphaRotatedT := wPng.AlphaScanline[ Rht ];
        AlphaSizeRot := Integer(wPng.AlphaScanline[1])-Integer(wPng.AlphaScanline[0]);
        AlphaSizeOrg := Integer(PNGOriginal.AlphaScanline[1])-Integer(PNGOriginal.AlphaScanline[0]);
      end
      else
      begin
        AlphaRowT := nil;
        AlphaStartPtr := nil;
        AlphaRotatedT := nil;
        AlphaSizeRot := 0;
        AlphaSizeOrg := 0;
      end;

      for j := Rht downto 0 DO   //1/8/00
      begin //for j
        jPrime := 2*j - NewHeight + 1 ;
        for i := Rwi downto 0 DO   //1/8/00
        begin //for i
          iPrime := 2*i - NewWidth   + 1;
          iOriginal := ( ROUND( iPrime*CosTheta - jPrime*sinTheta ) + Owi ) div 2;

          if ( iOriginal >= 0 ) and ( iOriginal <= Owi ) then
          begin //inside
            jOriginal := ( ROUND( iPrime*sinTheta + jPrime*cosTheta ) + Oht ) div 2 ;
            if ( jOriginal >= 0 ) and ( jOriginal <= Oht ) then
            begin    //1/8/00
              RowRotatedT[i] := pRGBTripleArray(Integer(RowStartPtr) + (jOriginal * RowSizeOrg))[iOriginal];
              if assigned(AlphaRotatedT) then
                AlphaRotatedT[i] := pByteArray(Integer(AlphaStartPtr) + (jOriginal * AlphaSizeOrg))[iOriginal];
            end
            else
            begin //set Transparent
              if Assigned(AlphaRotatedT) then
                AlphaRotatedT[i] := 0;
              RowRotatedT[i] := TransparentT;
            end;
          end //inside
          else
          begin //Set Transpaarent;
            if Assigned(AlphaRotatedT) then
              AlphaRotatedT[i] := 0;
            RowRotatedT[i] := TransparentT;
          end;
        end; //for i
        Dec(Integer(RowRotatedT), RowSizeRot) ;
        if assigned(AlphaRotatedT) then
          Dec(Integer(AlphaRotatedT), AlphaSizeRot) ;
      end;//for j
      PNGRotated.Assign(wPng);
    finally
      wPng.Free;
    end;
  end //non-zero rotation
  else
  begin //Zero rotation         
    if PNGRotated <> PNGOriginal then
      PNGRotated.Assign(PNGOriginal);
  end;
end; {RotatePNG}
```

Comment: You can still find a copy of TPNGImage that you can use for Delphi 7 available on the net.

Comment: Ryan,this code is what i use and it depends on looping over the pixels. and as my image 's dimension is large , it takes a long time that's why i'm searching for a component that may rotate it quickly :)

Comment: @SaraSaeed, what are the dimensions of your images?

Comment: 1716 x 938 this is one of my images, the problem that i use this on a medical monitor which is very hi res :)

Comment: How do you expect to be able to rotate an image without the algorithm stepping over each pixel? Any library that rotates an image to an arbitrary angle will have to address every pixel in the image and run it through a matrix/algorithm of some sort...

Comment: @SaraSaeed This new code I've just posted keeps the alpha channel intact during the rotate.  It currently only works for `RGBALPHA`, but I don't think it would take much work to make it work with `GRAYSCALEALPHA`.