# Card flip animation in FireMonkey Mobile

Tags: image, delphi, animation, firemonkey, flip

I want realize the flip animation effect using Embarcadero XE6 for develope FireMonkey Mobile Application for IPhone and Android

i have founded the effect into Embarcadero XE6 for Delphi:

[Playing card flip animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585068/playing-card-flip-animation)

It's possible convert the source code from Delphi to FireMonkey Mobile?

Comment: Probably can be done with descendants of TAnimation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possable. But nothing automatic that i know of. You would have to manually do it.

Look at the firemonkey help 
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE3/en/FMX.MetropolisUIFlipViewDemo_Sample

and what it looks like..
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SxhAvw37lEw

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code may give you a headstart for a 3D-cardflip using Firemonkey.

```
procedure TFormMain.Flip( aTabControl: TTabControl; aFront, aBack: TTabItem; aBkColor: TAlphaColor; aDirection: TFlipDirection ) ;
var
  Viewport: TViewport3D;
  R: TRectangle3D;
  bmpFront: TBitmap;
  bmpBack: TBitmap;
  matFront: TTextureMaterialSource;
  matBack: TTextureMaterialSource;
  Depth: extended;
  Angle: extended;
begin
  // Create a viewport and let it overlap aControl
  Viewport := TViewport3D.Create(nil);
  Viewport.BoundsRect := aTabControl.BoundsRect;
  Viewport.Position.X := aTabControl.Position.X;
  Viewport.Position.Y := aTabControl.Position.Y;
  Viewport.Color := aBkColor;
  Viewport.Parent := Self;

  // Create a flat 3d-rectangle and let it fully contain the Viewport
  R := TRectangle3D.Create(Viewport);
  R.Parent := Viewport;
  R.Projection := TProjection.Screen;
  R.Width := Viewport.Width;
  R.Height := Viewport.Height;
  R.Depth := 0;

  // Create a texture for the front and the back
  matFront := TTextureMaterialSource.Create(Viewport);
  aTabControl.ActiveTab := aFront;
  matFront.Texture := aTabControl.MakeScreenshot;
  R.MaterialSource := matFront;

  matBack := TTextureMaterialSource.Create(Viewport);
  aTabControl.ActiveTab := aBack;
  matBack.Texture := aTabControl.MakeScreenshot;
  matBack.Texture.FlipHorizontal;
  R.MaterialBackSource := matBack;

  // Do the flip
  Depth := 10;
  R.Position.Z := Depth;
  case aDirection of
    fdNormal : Angle := 180;
    fdReverse: Angle := -180;
  end;
  R.AnimateFloatWait( 'Position.Z', Depth, 0.1, TAnimationType.InOut, TInterpolationType.Linear );

  R.AnimateFloatWait( 'RotationAngle.Y', Angle, 0.5,
                      TAnimationType(cbAnimationType.ItemIndex),   {best is In}
                      TInterpolationType(cbInterpolationType.ItemIndex) );  {best is Back}
  R.AnimateFloatWait( 'Position.Z', 0, 0.1, TAnimationType.InOut, TInterpolationType.Linear);

  // Clear viewport and its children
  Viewport.DisposeOf;
end;
```