# How do I properly display a combined image in a Delphi `tstringgrid` component

Tags: delphi, bitmap, imagelist, tstringgrid

I have a game program that requires the user to select from 50+ images to place on a 9x9 game board grid with a `timage` in each position. For the user to place the images, I am providing a `tstringgrid` which displays various images from a `timagelist`. The actual images are graphic symbols created in `.png` format with transparent regions to allow the background color of the image's parent to show through when displayed. The image selected from the `tstringgrid` displays correctly on the game board `timage` components, but not in the 'tstringgrid'. The `tstringgrid` displays an image's transparent areas as black which is unsightly and makes many of the symbols unreadable.

I have used the following code to load the `tstringgrid`:

```
procedure TImageForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  r, c, n : Integer;
  img:TImage;
begin
  //assign a value to each cell to connect with imagelist.
  //see StringGrid1DrawCell
  img := timage.Create(nil);
  try
    n := -1;
    with StringGrid1 do begin
      for r := 0 to RowCount - 1 do begin
        for c:= 0 to ColCount - 1 do  begin
          inc(n);
          Cells[c,r] := IntToStr(n);
          ImageList1.GetBitmap(n, img.Picture.Bitmap);
//          ImageList1.AddMasked(Img.Picture.Bitmap, clBlack);
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    img.Free;
  end;
end;
```

What I need to do is revise the bitmap retrieved from the list before it is displayed.

I am attempting to do this as follows:

```
procedure TForm1.FillBkgd (bmp : tbitmap;clr : tcolor);
//which is the imagelist index for the image
var
  bmp1  : tbitmap;

begin
  bmp1 := tbitmap.create;

  try
     bmp1.Width := 50;
     bmp1.Height := 50;

     with Bmp1.Canvas do begin
      Brush.Color := clr;  //stringgrid1.color;
      Brush.Style := bsSolid;
      FillRect(rect(0,0,50, 50));
     end;

     bmp1.Canvas.Draw(0,0, bmp);
     bmp:= bmp1;
  finally
    bmp1.free;

  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.StringGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOEP312NzsE}
var
  bmp : tbitmap;
  s : string;
  aCanvas: TCanvas;
  n : integer;
begin
  inherited;

  if not Assigned (Imagelist1) then   //or (Arow = 0) or (aCol in [0,5])
    exit;
  bmp := tbitmap.create;
  try
    s := (Sender as TStringGrid).Cells [aCol, ARow];
    // Draw ImageX.Picture.Bitmap in all Rows in Col 1
    aCanvas := (Sender as TStringGrid).Canvas;
    // Clear current cell rect
    aCanvas.FillRect(Rect);
    // Draw the image in the cell
    n := strtoInt (s);
    ImageList1.GetBitmap(n, Bmp);

    FillBkgd (bmp,clRed); //stringgrid.color

    aCanvas.StretchDraw(Rect,bmp);

  finally

  end;
end;
```

My attempts to combine the symbol image with a colored background before placing it in the stringgrid have failed. It is unclear to me whether I am failing to create a solid colored bitmap or am not successfully joining the image to the background.

Comment: Why are you using TStringGrid (which as it's name suggests is designed to display strings) instead of TDrawGrid?

Comment: @KenWhite I used `tstringgrid` because I was familiar with it.  I will check out `tDrawgrid`, but won't I have the same problem joining the images with a background in the component canvas?

Comment: I don't know. What specific Delphi version are you using? Did you try setting the bitmap's `PixelFormat` to `pf32bit` before drawing to it? The specific reason *not* to use the `TStringGrid` is that it creates  `TStringList`s in the background for rows and columns that aren't necessary if you're not using them, which is a waste of resources.

Comment: @KenWhite I am using 10.3 community.  pf32bit has no affect

Comment: Definitely use `TDrawGrid` instead of `TStringGrid`. Or even `TPaintBox`. But either way, you should use `TImageList.Draw()` to draw the stored images directly on a `Canvas`, instead of using `TImageList.GetBitmap()` +  `Canvas.Draw()`. Otherwise, look at putting `TImage` controls in a `TGridPanel` and let the VCL handle all of the drawing for you.

Answer (score 3):

Function `FillBkgd` has big problems with the quality of the code.

```
     bmp:= bmp1;
  finally
    bmp1.free;    
  end;
```

All object variables are pointers. `bmp` and `bmp1` objects point to one area of ​​memory that you are freeing. This leads to Access Violation. You are lucky that the pointer is not returned from the function. Function `FillBkgd` does not work. To get the result, you could use `bmp.Assign(bmp1);`.

I see a lot of redrawing the picture of ImageList (draw to `Bmp`, draw to `Bmp1`, draw `ACanvas`). After the first transformation transparency information is lost. Therefore at this moment it is necessary to change the background color.

```
s := (Sender as TStringGrid).Cells [aCol, ARow];
// Draw ImageX.Picture.Bitmap in all Rows in Col 1
aCanvas := (Sender as TStringGrid).Canvas;
// Clear current cell rect
aCanvas.FillRect(Rect);
// Draw the image in the cell
n := strtoInt (s);

//new lines
bmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
bmp.Canvas.FillRect(TRect.Create(0, 0, ImageList1.Width, ImageList1.Height));
//new lines
ImageList1.GetBitmap(n, Bmp);

//deleted lines
//FillBkgd (bmp,clRed); //stringgrid.color

aCanvas.StretchDraw(Rect,bmp);
```

And do not forget to fill out `finally` to free `bmp`.

Comment: Your corrections successfully worked for a bitmap image in the `imagelist` with a transparency color set to the background.  The result is problematic since the background if the images varies as the pixels get close to the actual symbol resulting in a  poor rendering.

Comment: If the image in the `imagelist` was originally a .png with transparent pixels, the image is still rendered as black and the background color is not displayed.

Comment: " I see a lot of redrawing...After the first transformation information is lost." I'm not sure I understand, could you clarify which step in the code does that occur?

Comment: I checked again with `.png`, it works for me. Background is red.

Comment: The best way would be if you draw a slice on a `TStringGrid`. `ImageList1.Draw(aCanvas, 0, 0, n);`Maybe you will resize the png-images before placing them on the `TImageList`. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437714/resize-png-image